# Roslyn code analysis spell checker fails to recognize a code identifier within an interpolated string literal

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, roslyn-code-analysis

Code like this:

```
throw new ConfigurationException($"{nameof(EnvelopeOutputElement)} and {nameof(EnvelopeOutputStartMarkup)} are mutually exclusive");
```

results in a Code Analysis error CA2204 - Correct the spelling of the unrecognized token 'EnvelopeOutputElement' in the literal '"EnvelopeOutputElement and EnvelopeOutputStartMarkup are mutually exclusive"'.

However, code analysis already knows the words "envelope", "output" and "element" and it has no objections to an object property identifier being spelt 'EnvelopeOutputElement'.  Isn't it the point of the `nameof` operation to hint to the compiler that 'EnvelopeOutputElement' is required to be spelt exactly like the identifier?